# How to upgrade openresty with or without downtime

Tags: nginx, openresty

All,

I have few servers that have openresty installed and the version running on it is `nginx version: openresty/1.9.7.2`

How can i upgrade it to 1.11.5.2.

I have seen the documentation but things are not getting clear. Can someone please provide the detailed steps of the same.

Comment: How is the older version installed? Using packages or compiled from source?

Comment: Its installed using tar files. Yes from source

Comment: run `nginx -V` on the old version and check the compilation flags, use the same flags on the new version and add anything extra you need. Then compile the new version. Use `nginx -s stop` to stop old one and run `make install` in new version`. Check `nginx -v` and `nginx -V` to make sure the latest version is there. Then start nginx using whichever way it was running earlier. If it was running through server then use the same, else just run `nginx` command

Comment: nginx -v gives :  https://pastebin.com/raw/iHqqRzwT

Comment: can you give in answer od any step by step command .

Comment: Yes so you would need to copy each plugin (you should though copy the latest version of them from their source as well). See this article as well, will help you a bit http://tarunlalwani.com/post/building-nginx-with-lua/

Comment: I did the upgrade but the version was not upgraded

Comment: Try using `which nginx` and `ps auxe | grep nginx` and see if the path is correct or not

Comment: My nginx version is still not upgraded. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty late reply, but I just performed an upgrade from OpenResty 1.13.6.2 to 1.15.8.2. I'm running OpenResty in AWS/EC2 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I just followed the Ubuntu guide to install at [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html)

I did this on a backup instance to make sure everything worked, then applied the upgrade to my Live instance. All of my configs were intact and unchanged.

```
# install some prerequisites needed by adding GPG public keys (could be removed later)
sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends wget gnupg ca-certificates

# import our GPG key:
wget -O - https://openresty.org/package/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# for installing the add-apt-repository
sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common

# add the our official APT repository:
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://openresty.org/package/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"

# to update the APT index:
sudo apt-get update

# Then you can install openresty:

sudo apt-get -y install openresty

# check the new version:

openresty -v

# restart openresty

sudo service openresty restart
```